# Sum of forces in frame

Tags: structural-engineering

For the sum of forces about x axis = 0  , how do we know there is a 1.73kN force and also the 0.81kN force ? Where are they coming from ? Can someone explain about it ?

Secondly , where are the fixed moments of 100kNm come from ? 
[image: rwr]

[image: fsf]